# Some mobile browsers do not open certain website, nothing on apache access log

Tags: apache

Got quite odd problem with one website. Website is previously made by someone else and I am updating it. Problem is that some mobile browsers do not even attempt to open the site. When I try to open the site with Symbian N8 default browser it just stops at 5% of load and then there is message "Could not open the website, check your connection" after a minute or two. But if I try to open the site on same phone with Opera Mini or Opera mobile it works fine. I heard that some other people also have problems opening this site on tablet or on phones.

Apache access log does not show anything when connecting with symbian default browser. Also if I remove .htaccess which has some rules, it doesn't help. Even when I add die("test"); to first line of page.php (which is loaded first by .htaccess) it doesn't show that on those mobile browsers where it does not work.

Comment: Can you share the link to the website?

Comment: ok, telehaku (dot) fi

Comment: It seems that its same issue for other websites on that same server. So I guess its apache vhost thing.

Comment: (Solved) Reason was that firewall was blocking certain IP ranges which usually happened to be on use in mobile devices with certain service providers.